# class constructor initalization with a map second argument

Tags: c++, dictionary, constructor, initialization

I got a map like

```
  typedef float(*function)(vector<int>);
  map < string, function> mymap{
        { "maximum", &maxValue },
        { "minimum", &minValue },
        {... , ...},
  };
```

and got the definitions for functions that I used in the map as

```
   float maxValue(vector<int> v){
       auto cit = max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
       return *cit;
   }
```

and a similar function definitions for other functions that I used in the above map definition.

I got a class with two private data variables in a .h file as "string value;" and "float aggregate"

Now, my question is I want to define a constructor for this class and initialize the object's member data in.cpp file with values as

```
  // aggregates is my class name
 aggregates::aggregates(string val, const vector<int>& v): value(val), aggregate(.....)//here is my problem how can I initialize aggregate from the map that I mentioned above.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to copy the vector every time you try to calculate the maximum?

Comment: This looks less like a question and more like "do my homework for me"

Comment: If you're using C++11, you could rather use `std::function` in place of a typedef for a function pointer.

Comment: @JBL: I'd assume pre-C++11 since there the initializer list part is trivial.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Yes, but post-C++11, using a function pointer prevents you from using lambda. Also, way uglier syntax.

Comment: I would pass vector as const reference.

Comment: Even if we pass vector as const reference, the constructor's second argument is a vector and the aggregate type is a float. How can I resolve this?

Comment: No, it's not necessary to copy the vector in all your functions. Pass by const reference and make a local copy if you need to.

Comment: `float maxValue(vector<int> v)` This makes a copy of the vector which is inefficient. Use `float maxValue(const vector<int>& v)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
class aggregates
{
private:
    float aggregate;
    string value;
public:
    aggregates(const string & val, const vector<int> & v, const map <string, function> & mymap) : value(val)
    {
        aggregate = mymap.at(value)(v); // instead of mymap[value](v), due to const&
    }
};
```

Comment: oops instead of map I need a vector in the constructor. How can I do that

Comment: -1 Unnecessarily inefficient solution. Copies the whole map just to access one element.

Comment: You didn't take the leap from that to also pass the string and vector by reference. Your code may also modify the original state of the map if the value is not present.